# MySQL order by points from 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have MySQL 3 tables, items (which in this case are lodging properties and the data is simplified below), amenities that the properties might offer, and amenities_index which is a list of item ids and amenity ids for each amenity offered. The end user can select any number of amenities they want and I want to return the results in order of the number of amenities that match what they are looking for. So, if they search for 3 different amenities, I want the items listed that offer all 3, then those that offer 2, 1 and finally the rest of the items. I have a query that I think is working for getting the results in the correct order, but I was hoping that I could also return a point value based on the matches, and that's where I'm running into trouble. My SQL skills are a bit lacking when it comes to more complex queries.

Here is an example query I have that returns the results in the correct order:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
ORDER BY 
(
     SELECT count(*) AS points 
     FROM `amenities_index` 
     WHERE 
       (amenity_id = 1 || amenity_id = 2) 
       AND amenities_index.item_id = items.id
) DESC
```

And here is what the tables are structured like. Any help is appreciated.

```
items table
id  name    
1   location 1
2   location 2
3   location 3
4   location 4

amenities table
id  name
1   fireplace
2   television
3   handicapped accessible
4   kitchenette
5   phone

amenities_index
item_id amenity_id
1       2
1       3
1       5
2       1
2       2
2       6
3       2
3       3
3       4
3       5
```

Comment: please post expected result set.

Comment: Gordon Linoff provided exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move your expression into the `select` clause:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT count(*) AS points 
        FROM `amenities_index` ai
        WHERE amenity_id in (1, 2) AND
              ai.item_id = i.id
       ) as points
FROM items i
ORDER BY points desc;
```

You can also do this as a `join` query with aggregation:

```
SELECT i.*, ai.points
FROM items i join
     (select ai.item_id, count(*) as points
      from amenities_index ai
      where amenity_id in (1, 2)
     ) ai
     on ai.item_id = i.id
ORDER BY ai.points desc;
```

In most databases, I would prefer this version over the first one.  However, MySQL would allow the first in a view but not the second, so it has some strange limitations under some circumstances.